# Does JRuby on Rails have more 3rd party libraries than Play framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, playframework-2.0

I know it used to be the case, per this article for example: http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/rails-vs-django-vs-play-frameworks/

Is it still the case?

I particularly care about JavaScript libraries, since javascript is not my strong suit.

Comment: Why no answers? Do people use JRuby on Rails?

Comment: Just checked google trends, and JRuby seems hardly used at all, even without rails. http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=ruby%20on%20rails%2C%20jruby&cmpt=q&tz=  I did not know that. Hmm..